# Blazor Publish Failed

Tags: .net-core, blazor, webassembly

I'm doing some tests with Blazor and WebAssembly and I've been following a few of the tutorials over at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I can build and run my test project just fine. However, when I try to publish either the Blazor Client or Blazor Server in Visual Studio 2019, I get an error message that says:

```
Publish failed
Publish has encountered an error.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It then makes reference to a log file, which I've checked and it contains the following.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.CreatePublishServiceProvider(IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.CreateViewAsync(IVsHierarchy project, IAsyncServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Provider.PublishProjectDesignerTabProvider.<CreateViewAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug because Blazor WebAssembly is still in preview or if there is something wrong with my set up. I've tried googling this error, but it turns up very little.

So I'm just wondering if anyone else that has had a play with Blazor and WebAssembly has seen this error before and if they worked out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this before but not since VS 2017.
The work around used to be:

- In Visual Studio click Tools->Import and Export Settings and export your current settings, in case it all goes brexit
- Close Visual Studio
- Delete everything in C:\Users%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- Delete everything in C:\Users%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
- Delete everything in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio [version number]\Common7\IDE, if applicable
- Delete everything in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio [version number]\Common7\IDE, if applicable
- At a command prompt, navigate to Visual Studio and run `devenv /resetuserdata`, this will purge Visual Studio.
- Open Visual Studio and reimport or reenter the settings you need.

Good luck.